# Chamar a função em PHP várias vezes ou armazenar a função em variável?

Tags: php

Eu estava aqui criando alguns arquivos de loop quando eu me deparei com a seguinte dúvida:

Ao invés de eu chamar uma função que retorna o dado todas as vezes
Ex:

```
<?php
if (pegar_dado('nome_dado') != '') {
    echo pegar_dado('nome_dado');
} ?>
```

Não seria mais prático e **talvez** melhor e mais leve armazenar a variável e depois fazer o resto?

```
<?php
$pega1 = pegar_dado('nome_dado');
if ($pega1 != '') {
 echo $pega1;
}
```

O que eu quero saber é, com a experiência de vocês, qual dos dois métodos é melhor? Mais leve? Existe diferença no uso de memória nos dois casos?

E qual dos dois métodos vocês recomendam utilizar?

Comment: Certamente a 2ª opção, imagine ter que executar uma função 1000 vezes... pode ser pouca a alteração no processo, mas vai ocorrer, sendo que, uma vez executada e salva numa variável, não há necessidade de execução novamente.

Comment: Sabe me dizer se essa função "pegar dado" será executada TODAS as vezes que eu chamar essa função? digo, será que ela vai consultar meu banco de dados todas as vezes que eu chamar ela? e se eu armazenar em uma variável, será que o banco de dados será consultado apenas uma vez?

Comment: Se a função faz uma consulta ao banco, sim, será feito a consulta toda vez que chamar a função. Chamando apenas uma vez será apenas uma consulta feita.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Se a função for chamada no arquivo várias vezes ela faz a consulta, ok, mas se a função for armazenada em variável e a variável for chamada varias vezes, a consulta será feita 1 ou várias vezes?

Comment: Apenas uma vez. O resultado será armazenado em memória e reutilizado.

Comment: Depende do caso. Se a função for "pegarIdSequencial" (e fizer o que o nome diz) e vc armazenar o resultado, não vai ser um ID sequencial. Qual usar? Depende do resultado pretendido. Em geral, se quer sempre a situação atual tem que chamar a função sempre, se quer o valor original, mesmo que algo externo mude o resultado da função, armazene.

Answer (score -3):

A segunda maneira não é aconselhável.

Existem estratégias de cacheamento para casos que envolvam IO. Mas a função sempre deve ser chamada.

De forma geral, execução de uma função é mais custosa que acessar uma região de memória com um valor já atribuído. Mas se isso não envolver IO, não fará muita diferença na execução do seu programa.

Contudo, você perde toda a flexibilidade do seu sistema. Imagine que no futuro você precise tomar uma decisão de buscar esse dado de formas diferentes durante a execução do programa. Ou que você precise desativar o cachê desse recurso no futuro. Utilizando a segunda abordagem, você teria que substituir em todos os lugares para remover esse cachê.

Enquanto que se você deixa a responsabilidade de fazer cachê dentro da função, você alteraria apenas em um lugar.

Exemplo de cachê dentro da função usando OO:

```
class interfaceAcessoDado {

  private static $dadoCacheado;

  public function pegaDado()
  {
       if( self::$dataCache === null )
           self::$dadoCacheado = $this->pegaDadoDoBD();
       return self::$dadoCacheado;
  }

  private function pegaDadoDoBD()
  {
       // Busca esse dado 
       return $dado;
   }
}
```

Comment: Não consegui perceber a diferença/vantagem de se armazenar o valor "em cache" em uma variável dentro da classe com armazenar na variável como perguntado que você disse não ser aconselhável. Poderia detalhar melhor?

Comment: Vou apontar duas vantagens. A primeira é que quem está consumindo esse valor não precisa saber como ele está sendo recuperado. Ou seja, se você precisar usar essa função de diversos lugares, não precisa ficar repetindo código de verificação se a variável existe senão busca do BD. É sempre a mesma função que retorna o valor que você quer, independente de como isso seja feito. Fazendo isso, é como se você construísse uma interface para acesso ao dado.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a segunda vantagem é que se tiver dois lugares totalmente distintos que estão acessando o mesmo dado, o primeiro realiza a consulta e guardar essa info na variável estática. Se um segundo local do código precisar acessar o mesmo dado, ele já irá consumir o valor dessa variável. Mas tudo sem ter que ficar pensando se já buscou esse dado ou não. Essa variável estática existe em tempo de execução de uma processo. Mas se no futuro vc quiser algo mais sofisticado, pode deixar em um redis por exemplo e todos os pontos do consomem essa função nem "saberão" de onde tá vindo o dado.